# Why are icons missing and text compressed in IE11?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I created this site in Bootstrap 4. And it works on all browsers perfectly as you can see below:

[image]

but when i open on Internet Explorer 11, this is what happen:

[image]

I try a lot of things but still dont work. This is the code im using:

```css
.big-table {
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .big-table {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
  }
}

.big-table table {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .big-table table {
    table-layout: unset;
  }
}

.tbl-header {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.tbl-header th {
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  word-break: break-all;
  width: 150px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .tbl-header th {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}

.tbl-content {
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.tbl-content .checkbox label {
  font-size: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .tbl-content .checkbox label {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}

.tbl-content td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.tbl-content td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .tbl-content td {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .tbl-content td {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}

.tbl-sub-header {
  background-color: #007de8;
}

.tbl-sub-header td {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.tbl-sub-header td .inputer {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  /* width: 100%; */
  width: 115px;
  /* font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 1.2rem; */
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #646464;
}

.tbl-sub-header td .inputer::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.tbl-sub-header td .inputer[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.tbl-sub-header td .inputer[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.tbl-sub-header td .inputer[type='number'] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 825px) {
  .tbl-sub-header td {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}

.tbl-sub-header td .select-inputer {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: #ffffff url(../images/select-arrow.svg) right 5px center no-repeat;
  background-size: 22px 22px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tbl-sub-header td .select-inputer::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.tbl-sub-header td .date-inputer {
  background: #ffffff url(../images/icon-calendar.svg) right 5px center no-repeat;
}

.tbl-tower {
  background-color: #646464;
}

.tbl-tower td {
  color: #ffffff;
  /* text-align: left; */
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none;
}

input::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input::-webkit-clear-button {
  display: none;
}

input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
}

input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator:hover {
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* for custom scrollbar for webkit browser*/


/* EXCEPTIONS */

.row-c-grey {
  background-color: #646464 !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.th-w-50 {
  width: 50% !important;
}

.td-w-40 {
  max-width: 40px !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .td-w-40 {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .display-none {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

.table-permissions tbody td:last-child {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  color: #000000 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="big-table">
      <div class="tbl-header">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Torre</th>
              <th>Catálogo</th>
              <th>Estado</th>
              <th>GT</th>
              <th>Data</th>
              <th>Hora</th>
              <th>Urgente</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="tbl-content">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
          <tbody>

            <tr class="tbl-sub-header">
              <td class="input-group checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox-16" checked="checked" validate="">
                <label for="checkbox-16">Global</label></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>
                <select class="inputer select-inputer" name="" id="" type="select">
                  <option value="">João Mendes</option>
                  <option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
                  <option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
                  <option value="Item 3">Item 3</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td class="">
                <input class="inputer date-inputer" name="" id="date" type="date" value="2019-01-31" min="2019-01-01" max="2019-12-31">

              </td>
              <td>
                <select class="inputer select-inputer" name="" id="" type="select">

                  <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
                  <option value="14:00">14:00</option>

                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select class="inputer select-inputer" name="" id="" type="select">

                  <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
                  <option value="Não">Não</option>

                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tbl-tower">
              <td class="input-group checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox-15" checked="checked" validate="">
                <label for="checkbox-15">GTE 3</label></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="input-group checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox-10" checked="checked" validate="">
                <label for="checkbox-10">IXP.18.37595</label>
                <i class="icon-trd-teste2" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Redistribuída 2 vezes"></i>
              </td>
              <td>GlobalConnect Equipamentos</td>
              <td>Em Provisão</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="input-group checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox-11" checked="checked" validate="">
                <label for="checkbox-11">IXS.18.37595</label>
              </td>
              <td>GlobalPhone Unify Connect</td>
              <td>Em Provisão</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tbl-tower">
              <td class="input-group checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox-12" checked="checked" validate="">
                <label for="checkbox-12">GTE 4</label>
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="input-group checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox-13" checked="checked" validate="">
                <label for="checkbox-13">IXS.18.37595</label>
              </td>
              <td>...</td>
              <td>Em Provisão</td>
              <td>...</td>
              <td>...</td>
              <td>...</td>
              <td>...</td>
            </tr>


          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: your snippet looks ok to me in IE11.

Comment: There are a lot of differences in those screenshots. Is something not loading in IE (404 errors)? It looks like maybe a missing font.

Comment: Actually, I did not put the whole code cause  the size. But there are icons. Which I did not put in the code above, but the errors keep happening even without these icons.